# Send Random Item in MongoDb with Discord.Py

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py, nextcord

Im attempting to make my bot send a **random** value of a specific field

```
#edit
@bot.command()
async def edit(ctx):
    edit = db.edit.aggregate({ 'edit': { 'edit': 1 } })
    await ctx.reply(edit)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdxGl.png

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide a lot more information, but if it's anything like a list of values you could just separate it using the `.split` method and then using `random.choice()` to pick a random value.

I would also recommend you consider using some sort of relational database eg SQL as it will better serve your needs.